# Why is Docker not picking up code changes, despite 'prune all', 'build no cache' and then 'up force recreate'?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm dockerising a django app (webapp).  However, when I make code changes they do not seem to be reflected when the container is rebuilt.

I'm trying to test that I can hit 'app' but the name has changed to 'newapp'.

testcase.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests

class TestServerUp(TestCase):

    def testhitendpoint(self):
        r = requests.get(host='app', port=1234)

        self.assertEquals(r.status_code, 200)
```

Running the command `sudo docker exec -it webapp python manage.py test tests.testcase` fails because host should be 'newapp'

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='app', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd97d430550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

I change the test case to:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests

class TestServerUp(TestCase):

    def testhitendpoint(self):
        r = requests.get(host='newapp', port=1234)

        self.assertEquals(r.status_code, 200)
```

I bring the containers down:
`sudo docker-compose -f ./deploy/docker-compose.yaml down`

I remove the containers from docker:
`sudo docker system prune --all --volumes -f`, then  `sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -aq)` just to be sure.

I rebuild the containers:
`sudo docker-compose -f ./deploy/docker-compose.yaml build --no-cache`

I then spin the containers up:
`sudo docker-compose -f ./deploy/docker-compose.yaml up --force-recreate -d`

I run the tests again:
`sudo docker exec -it webapp python manage.py test tests.testcase`
(or `sudo docker exec -it [container-id] python manage.py test tests.testcase`)

and I get exactly the same error message:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='app', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd97d430550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

Looking in the container (`sudo docker exec -it webapp /bin/bash`)
and running `cat tests/testcase.py` shows the original code for the first testcase (host='app'), not the revised one (host='newapp').

deploy/docker-compse.yaml

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  app:
    build: ../webapp
    container_name: webapp
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - app_data:/webapp
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
      - ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
      - POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    depends_on:
      - db
 
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  app_data:
```

webapp/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.7-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /webapp
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV USE_DOCKER=true
# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev
COPY requirements.txt /webapp/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
COPY . /webapp/
RUN mkdir /webapp/staticfiles
```

webapp/entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Collect static files
echo "Collect static files"
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Apply database migrations
echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate --noinput

# Start server
echo "Starting server"
gunicorn webapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I think that docker is either pulling from a cache that I've not deleted, or  'docker exec -it' is being run against an older container.

Any suggestions for what I may have overlooked would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try docker-compose build and docker-compose up

Comment: I have a similar setup and I typically run: `docker-compose up --force-recreate --always-recreate-deps -V --build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container declares that a Docker named volume should be mounted over your application tree:

```yaml
volumes:
  - app_data:/webapp
```

Delete this block entirely.

This apparently works the first time you run it, because when Docker creates a new named volume and mounts it into a container, *the first time only* it copies the contents from the image into the volume.  The *second* time you run the container, though, the (old) contents of the volume replace what was in the (updated) image.  There's no way to cause Docker to automatically update the volume content without manually copying it yourself in something like an entrypoint script; it's easier to just remove the volume entirely.

Comment: That did it - thanks for the explanation!